# Modifying Script to include the Count of a each time a name appears from a table

Tags: perl, count

I have a script below that takes my FILE1 and parses out FILE2 only if the first column of FILE1 matches column number 10 of FILE2. So it will print out the rows I need. This part works great. The part I am having a tad bit of difficulty is inserting a sort of count for the output. The goal of the script is take column 10 at the end and produce an output. In my list there are 12 names and I want to get the count of each name. For the example below, I have used four names.

FILE1:

```
name1 15
name2 15
name2 30
name5 15
name4 10
name2 5
name2 5
```

FILE2:

```
23   15  5.4  1.3  5   55     128 21799 + 32    name2      1     77     0       1
23   20  5.4  1.3  5   55     128 7998 + 18     name4      1     77     0       1
23   20  5.4  1.3  6   55     128 9984 + 13     name4      1     77     1       1
23   20  5.4  1.3  7   55     128 7998 + 14     name5      1     77     2       1
23   20  5.4  1.3  6   55     128 994 + 14      name1      1     77     3
23   20  5.4  1.3  9   55     128 984 + 5       name7      1     77     4       1
23   20  5.4  1.3  5   55     128 99 + 5    name8      1     77     5       1
```

Expected Output

```
$VAR1 = {
      'name1' => 1,
      'name2' => 4,
      'name4' => 1,
      'name5' => 1,
    };

5   55     128 21799  32    name2         77     0       1
5   55     128 7998  18     name4         77     0       1
6   55     128 9984  13     name4         77     1       1
7   55     128 7998  14     name5         77     2       1
6   55     128 994  14      name1         77     3       1

name1 1
name2 1
name4 2
name5 1
```

You can test the script it works. The part I am having difficulty with is inserting the count of each name based on the output. The print \%x is a way of checking if my original list was truly used as I am working with a much larger set of data. If someone could point me the right direction on how to modify my script without changing it drastically that would be great. I feel like this script fulfills the majority of my needs even if it is not the most efficient way of doing it.

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my %x;

open(FILE1, $ARGV[0]) or die "Cannot open the file: $!";
 while (my $line = <FILE1>)  {
     my @array = split(" ", $line);
     $x{$array[0]}++;
 }
 close FILE1;

print Dumper( \%x );
my %count;
open(FILE2, $ARGV[1]) or die "Cannot open the file: $!";
while (my $line = <FILE2>)  {
    my @name = split(" ", $line);
    my $y = $name[9];
    if ( $x{ $y } ) {
        print join("  ", @name[4,5,6,7,9,11,12,13]), "\n";
$count{@name[9]}++;
    }
}
print Dumper (\%count);
close FILE2;
exit;
```

Script now counts. Just need to debug.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but that `join` might be more readable with an [array slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices): `join("  ", @name[4 .. 7, 9, 11 .. 13])`

Comment: @JimDavis Utter nit-pick, but you mean with *a single* array slice (the OP is already using a bunch of separate slices, although they're probably not aware of it). ;)

Comment: Oh! That's neat. Wasn't aware of this thanks.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot D'oh!  Nice catch.

Comment: @MrPeace Add `use warnings;` to the top of your script and you'll get a bunch of warnings like `Scalar value @name[4] better written as $name[4]`.

Comment: when i did that originally it said useless use of a constant. thats why i turned them off. the script works fine with warnings off.

Comment: You could create a hash similar to `%x` to keep track of the counts inside the last `if`, and at the end you could print out the content of the hash..

Comment: @MrPeace The solution to that is to fix the cause of the warning, not to disable warnings altogether. You should enable warnings (and strict) for every Perl script you write; they can save you a lot of debugging time.

Comment: Got it, will edit it and upload the fixed version when I have it.

Comment: @HåkonHægland didnt even think of that thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the "minimal" change would be to set the elements of `%x` to 0 in the `FILE1` loop, then check for `exists $x{$y}` in the `FILE2` loop and do `++$x{$y}` inside the condition body. Now at the end `%x` has the counts of all the occurrences.

The usual way (as mentioned in the comments of the question) would be to declare an additional `%count` and perform the same `++$count{$y}` inside the if block as in the above method.

The first has the advantage and disadvantage (depending on your needs) of reporting the count even when the name has zero found occurrences.